# How Can I Deselect a Button or Redefine the function of the Return Key in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, keypress

I'm making a calculator and I'm wondering how to make the enter key work as the equals sign. All other key bindings worked with keypress except delete which required a separate function attached to keydown. However, I set the RETURN key to perform the same function as the equals sign, and it instead just repeats the pressing of the last button pressed.

Comment: IMHO, don't try to bind a key to each button and don't allow the button to take focus. Instead let the key event trickle up to the window and handle it there.

Comment: A WinForms Form has two buttons properties: `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton` that map to the `<Enter>` and `<Esc>` keys. Just point the `AcceptButtin` property at you `Equals` button

Answer (score 0):

All WinForms have a property to handle this, `Accept Button`. You can find it right at the top of the Properties window for the form.

[image]

If your equal sign button is instantiated when the form is initialized, it should be available in the dropdown menu.

[image]

This property will automatically bind a button on your form to the "AcceptButton" which defaults to the ENTER key.

See [Form.AcceptButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) on the MSDN docs for more info.